# Can a cyclometer be used with any bicycle?

Tags: parts

I just want to know if a cyclometer can be used on any cycle or just on those made for racing or touring. Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: The simple answer is yes!

Comment: All you need to do is calculate the rolling circumference of your front wheel for each bike.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclometers I have owned counted wheelrevolutions by impulse of a circular lever on the cyclometer itself, most often mounted on the front fork. The impulse was from a solid peg mounted to a wheel spoke.

I have not seen such a cyclometer in the past 25 years.  Bike computers perform the similar functions, as well as others, depending on specific models.  Most bike computers operate from magnetic sensors which can be mounted or adapted to almost any cycle. Some feed the data from the sensor to a head unit mounted were it can be seen by a wire. In a few cases the supplied wire is too short to reach from a sensor (generally for pedal revolutions) to the head unit or alternative smart phone or watch read out unit.

Comment: We agree - a **cyclometer** counts wheel revolutions mechanically and can only tell you how far you've travelled.  They generally don't use batteries.   A **cycle computer** uses a magnet on a a spoke to count wheel revolutions and uses a small calculator to show speed and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cyclometer or bike computer (or an activity tracking app on a smartphone such as Strava) with any cycle no matter what your riding style is.

More expensive computers use GPS to track speed and distance, but also support wireless sensors that attache to wheels and crank for speed and pedaling speed.

Less expensive ones use a sensor that attaches to the frame or fork and s small magnet attached to a spoke.